# How to change the colour of skin in an image using Xcode?

Tags: ios, image-processing, xcode4, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating a new app in which either taking or selecting an existing photo of a person I want to have a control / action so that the skin colour can be changed. For example to show someone with pale skin what they would look like with a sun tan.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: You need to ask a specific programming question, not just post a requirement. What have you tried, why doesn't it work, that sort of thing.

Comment: Tams has just showed me CGImageCreateCopyWithColorSpace on the link below. http://bit.ly/GzHtyH. Do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the requirement, but this is a link to the Apple docs that will help you get started. Check out the part where you can mask certain colors. So if you allowed the user to tap somewhere where skin is exposed, retain a reference to the color and then mask it is one way you could tackle this problem. Here is the apple doc: http://bit.ly/GzHtyH

Hope this helps
Tams

Comment: Hi Tams, Thanks for the reply. CGImageCreateCopyWithColorSpace so I could use this function. When the user taps on the screen then the area tapped could change to a certain colour?